# Array push in for loop have different value in Object container

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im new to programming and just wondering why the output newContainer is different from what I have push inside the forloop. Check the console.log for details.

```
var data = [{
    Fruit: "Apple",
    Count: "1",
    Date: "2014"
}, {
    Fruit: "Banana",
    Count: "1",
    Date: "2015"
}, {
    Fruit: "Carrot",
    Count: "1",
    Date: "2014"
}, {
    Fruit: "Orange",
    Count: "1",
    Date: "2016"
}, {
    Fruit: "Apple",
    Count: "1",
    Date: "2012"
}, {
    Fruit: "Banana",
    Count: "1",
    Date: "2011"
}, {
    Fruit: "Apple",
    Count: "1",
    Date: "2010"
}];



var lineItemCount = new Array(5).fill(0);
var lineItems = ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Orange"];
var newContainer = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var checkItem = lineItems.indexOf(data[i].Fruit); //get index of item in lineItems

    lineItemCount[checkItem] = lineItemCount[checkItem] + 1;
    lineItemCount[0] = data[i].Date;

    newContainer.push(lineItemCount);
    console.log(lineItemCount);

};
console.log(newContainer);
```

Im trying to get the output like below. Thank you!

```
["2014", 1, 0, 0, 0],
["2015", 1, 1, 0, 0],
["2014", 1, 1, 1, 0],
["2016", 1, 1, 1, 1],
["2012", 2, 1, 1, 1],
["2011", 2, 2, 1, 1],
["2010", 3, 1, 1, 1],
```

Comment: Your desired output has 3 columns with numbers, but you have 4 fruits. How does that work?

Comment: Yeah your right, sorry my bad. I'll update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Your elements are pushed by reference. Just make a copy and then push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you push the same array over and over again to the result. Although at the moment of the *push*, the array has different values than the next *push*, an array is a reference, and so when the values inside the array are incremented, any reference to that array will *see* this, even those references you already pushed.

Here is corrected code which uses `slice(0)` to copy array elements into a new array which then is pushed:

```
// 5 elements, first one for date
var lineItemCount = new Array(5).fill(0);

var lineItems = [null, "Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Orange"];
var newContainer = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var checkItem = lineItems.indexOf(data[i].Fruit); //get index of item in lineItems

    lineItemCount[checkItem] = lineItemCount[checkItem] + 1;
    lineItemCount[0] = data[i].Date;

    newContainer.push(lineItemCount.slice(0)); // take array copy
    console.log(lineItemCount);

};
console.log(newContainer);
```

Note also the additional item in the array with fruit names. This makes sure you don't increment element at index 0 which you have reserved for the dates.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I now understand. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are pushed by reference. Just make a copy and then push.

For example, change `newContainer.push(lineItemCount);` to `newContainer.push(Array.from(lineItemCount));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use som helpers, one for the direct access to the indices of the fruit array positions and a hash table for the already inserted arrays in container.

The rest is checking if the date array already exist and if not to build one with empty values and the date in front of it. Then push it to `container`.

Now add the count to the appropriate date and column.

```js
var data = [{ Fruit: "Apple", Count: "1", Date: "2014" }, { Fruit: "Banana", Count: "1", Date: "2015" }, { Fruit: "Carrot", Count: "1", Date: "2014" }, { Fruit: "Orange", Count: "1", Date: "2016" }, { Fruit: "Apple", Count: "1", Date: "2012" }, { Fruit: "Banana", Count: "1", Date: "2011" }, { Fruit: "Apple", Count: "1", Date: "2010" }],
    lineItems = ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Orange"],
    container = [],
    items = {};

lineItems.forEach(function (a, i) { items[a] = i; });

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.Date]) {
        this[a.Date] = [a.Date].concat(lineItems.map(function () { return 0; }))
        container.push(this[a.Date]);
    }
    this[a.Date][items[a.Fruit] + 1] += +a.Count;
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(container, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```